# Backbone toJSON not rendering

Tags: json, backbone.js, model, render

when I use Backbone **toJSON** method of the model like this:

```
this.$el.html(this.model.toJSON());
```

It doesn't render model into view root element ( more than one attribute ).

But when I get one property from the model, like this;

```
 this.$el.html(this.model.get("city"));
```

It is rendered properly.

Also, when I use template in first case  (toJSON) - it is rendered fine.

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON());
```

Why is that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically `this.template` will be (in most of the cases) a compiled version of the `html template` which you have for the view.

It will have placeholders in it, and will take parameters with the same key as placeholders in the template. For example (Handlebars templates),

```
<section id="{{id}}">
  <header>{{header_text}}</header>
</section>
```

Considering the above code as a template, when you compile and store it in `this.template`, it returns a function, which takes a `json` object as a parameter, so now `this.template` is a function.

You can call it like below,

```
var html_text = this.template({
  id : "main_content",
  header_text : "Hi Welcome !!"
});

this.$el.html(html_text);
```

After the execution, `el`'s contents will be

```
<section id="main_content">
  <header>Hi Welcome !!</header>
</section>
```

So when you do `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON());`, it actually generates the required `json` parameter for the `this.template` method for you, hence works fine.

And as [Loamhoof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2211877/loamhoof) said, in `this.$el.html(this.model.get("city"));` you use the html method which will set the html content of the el based on the property value of the model.

Answer (score 4):

```
this.$el.html(this.model.toJSON());
```

You're using the `html` method of jQuery, which expects a string (or a DOM element, or a jQuery element), to display a JSON object.

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON());
```

Here you're using a `template` method which, I assume, is taking a JSON object to evaluate a template that will return you a string. The `html`method receives this string and displays it.

```
this.$el.html(JSON.stringify(this.model.toJSON()));
```

This would display the result of `this.model.toJSON()` (but won't do the same as using your `template` method).